# How are guns' "caliber" measured in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, blasters

I'm designing a blaster model and I wanted to know what system does the *Star Wars* universe measure "caliber" (blaster/cannon size) in? I'm interested in the Clone Wars era preferably. Legends and canon answers are accepted.

Comment: Some clarification: by blaster/cannon sizes I mean bore diameter not overall size.

Comment: Blasters come in various flavours including [light](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/SE-14r_light_repeating_blaster) and [heavy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Heavy_blaster_pistol).

Comment: Well yeah but I mean precise as defining an e-11 from a t-21 or a E-web from one of its cousins or parents

Comment: They are based on props for a movie. Only if the writers or prop-makers were concerned with this will be the information be available.

Comment: Reminds me of a certain scene from _Spaceballs_...

Comment: A phased plasma weapon in the 40 watt range?

Comment: @greenstone so watts?